# Installing Eric6 Python on Windows 10

Tags: python, qt, ide

I'm trying to install Eric6 IDE to develop Python GUI project with the help of Qt Designer.
I've already installed :

python-3.4.0.amd64

PyQt5-5.5-gpl-Py3.4-Qt5.5.0-x64

[image]

and when try to install Eric by executing install.py, it shows an error :

[image]

Qt Version: 5.5.0
Sorry, you must have Qt version 4.8.0 or better or
5.6.0 or better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error message is relatively clear. `eric6` requires Qt `4.8.x` OR `5.6.0` or newer. And you installed `PyQt5-5.5-gpl-Py3.4-Qt5.5.0-x64` which corresponds with the `Qt Version: 5.5.0` which you see in the UI.

Please install a newer Qt version.

The [installation documentation for eric](https://eric-ide.python-projects.org/eric-download.html) also explains how it supplies a script which would help installing QT:

> Note: The Qt development tools may be installed with the command C:\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe install pyqt5-tools instead.